# Programmatically configure ActiveRecordFacility for multiple databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to build a small application (ASP.NET MVC) that uses the plugin architecture. Along with Castle ActiveRecord Integration Facility. And I wish to let each plugin configure its own ActiveRecord behaviors. Like database connection string, proxy, etc..
However, I couldn't find a way to set multiple configurations without the use of web.config. The idea is to make this programmatically.

My goal is for each plugin in this system, if it defines its own ActiveRecord settings, the main application can set up next to ActiveRecordFacility these behaviors.

has someone do something like that?

P.S.: sorry, bad grammar...google translate...;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...the example in Lostechies works great. ([link text](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rssvihla/archive/2009/06/03/castle-activerecord-and-registering-classes-at-runtime.aspx))

Mauricio, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the ActiveRecord configuration programmatically using `InPlaceConfigurationSource` (lots of examples around), then after initializing ActiveRecord (in your own code), call the ActiveRecordFacility with the skipARInitialization flag. e.g.:

```
container.AddFacility("ar", new ActiveRecordFacility(true));
```

This tells the facility not to try to initialize ActiveRecord, so it picks up the existing configuration.

Comment: Uhm...almost there...what i want is to let the plugin (maybe two or more) configure its own ActiveRecord behaviors...like, BlogPlugin writes in database X while MailingPlugin writes in database Y...i found an example on LosTechies... http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rssvihla/archive/2009/06/03/castle-activerecord-and-registering-classes-at-runtime.aspx ...=/...i will try this first and post here the answer if it works. Tks!

Comment: @marcoaoteixeira: yes, that article uses InPlaceConfigurationSource, just as I said.